# How to display photos full screen in Flex

Tags: apache-flex

I give users the ability to put album in my Flex application. I want to add a feature when they can click a button to view photos full screen slide show.

How to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To change to full screen mode:

```
Application.application.stage.displayState = StageDisplayState.FULL_SCREEN;
```

To switch back to normal mode:

```
Application.application.stage.displayState = StageDisplayState.NORMAL;
```

Comment: Thank you I would modify it slighly for Flex 4: FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication.stage...etc